# passing on data from observe function to download

Tags: r, shiny

I got stuck on my first shiny app again. So far the App was runing fine, but now I wanted to download the plot I generated and I can not work out how to get the results out of the observe function. 
As I can not generate the plot outside the observe function, I was thinking I would assign the necessary data to a global variable useing `<<-`, but if I run a reactive function e.g. `df.selected.columns()` this seem to cause errors. 
Can someone give me a hint how to proceed?
Thank you so much for any suggestions! Aishe

Here is me code:

```
ui <- shinyServer(
  fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(

      tabPanel("Data upload",
               titlePanel("Data upload"),
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",multiple = TRUE, accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")),
                   tags$hr(),
                   checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE), radioButtons("sep", "Separator", choices = c(Comma = ",", Semicolon = ";",Tab = "\t"), selected = ","),
                   tags$hr(),
                   checkboxInput("disp", "Display",TRUE),
                   tags$hr(),

                   uiOutput("choose_first_column"),
                   uiOutput("choose_second_column"),
                   br()

                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   tableOutput("contents"),
                   tags$hr(),
                   tableOutput("tab"),
                   tags$hr(),
                   uiOutput("download"),
                   plotOutput("headplot")
                )
               )
      ),
      tabPanel("2","2"
      )  

    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

       observe({      
    req(input$file1)


      df <-  read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                      header = input$header,
                      sep = input$sep,
                      quote = input$quote)

      output$contents <- renderTable({
        (head(df))})

      output$choose_first_column <- renderUI({
        colnames <- names(df)
        selectInput("column_1", "Choose Date column", 
                    choices  = colnames,
                    selected = colnames)})

      output$choose_second_column <- renderUI({
        colnames <- names(df)
        selectInput("column_2", "Choose Variable column", 
                    choices  = colnames,
                    selected = colnames)})

      df.selected.columns <- reactive({
        df.columns <- df[,c(input$column_1,input$column_2)]
        return(df.columns)
      })

      output$tab <- renderTable({
        (head(df.selected.columns()))
      })

      Plot1 <- reactive({
        plot(head(df.selected.columns()[,2]))
      })

      output$headplot <- renderPlot({
        Plot1()
        })

#     This comes closest to what I wanted to do. However, now I can not select the columns anymore.            
#      try(result <<- head(df.selected.columns()[,2]),silent=T)
#     With this line it crushes straight away        
#      result <<- head(df.selected.columns()[,2])
       })

    output$download <- renderUI({
      if(!is.null(input$column_1) & !is.null(input$column_2)) {
        downloadButton('OutputPlot', 'Download Plot')
      }
    })

    output$OutputPlot <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('plot', '.pdf', sep='')
      },
      content=function(file){
        pdf(file)
        plot(result)
        dev.off()
      })

  })  

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Input data example:

```
date    time    level
01.01.2000  00:00:00    0.3724
01.01.2000  01:00:00    0.192
01.01.2000  02:00:00    -0.0252
```

Comment: It's hard to tell because the code isn't properly indented, but is everything in your server function enclosed in an `observe` function? If so, get rid of it. There's no reason for it. Ideally, you should never put a reactive function inside another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the `observe`
2. Make the loaded file a `reactive`

   - Update all references to `df` to `df()` since it's now a reactive expression
3. Add appropriate `req()` functions to prevent error messages
4. In your `downloadHandler` you have `plot(result)`, but there's no such thing as `result`. You want `Plot()` or `plot(df.selected.columns())`
5. You should be confirming that your selected delimiter is actually splitting the loaded table correctly before your return the loaded table. Without that, you'll get errors and strange results/

Here's the updated `df` and `downloadHandler` functions to get you started:

```
        df <- reactive({
            req(input$file1)
            read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                     header = input$header,
                     sep = input$sep,
                     quote = input$quote)
        })
```

---

```
        output$OutputPlot <- downloadHandler(
            filename = function() {
                paste('plot', '.pdf', sep='')
            },
            content=function(file){
                pdf(file)
                plot(head(df.selected.columns()[,2]))
                dev.off()
            })
```